# Idea on opening a .bak file

Tags: .net, sql-server, database

I am having this file called `somename.bak`. It is around 15mb in size. It is a database backup.

I want to open this file so that I can view its contents. I tried fileviewer software but of no use.

Can anyone suggest me how to open this .bak file?

Comment: It's most likely a SQL Server backup - you need to use SQL Server Management Studio to restore the backup to your SQL Server

Answer (score 3):

You can't open this file in a file viewer.

You have to use SQL Server management studio express and you should restore that database to view database.

First download and install sql server expression edition and sql server management studio from the microsoft site.

After installation open sql express management studio, connect to the local sql server and there in the databases list, you will get restore database option.

Basically you need to setup a sql server express

Comment: Worth noting is that usually, MSSQL .bak-files can only be restored to a SQL Server of the same version.

Comment: Well higher versions supports lower versions database backups. As I have worked with 2008, 2008 supports 2005 database backups also

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open the `.bak` file created by the SQL Server `BACKUP DATABASE` command and view table data within it.

The fact is that the `.bak` file is a *physical* backup of the database, which means the data is stored in it in the same form as it is stored on disk. There, the data is not stored in a human-readable form.

To inspect the data in the backup file, you must restore it. You can use either SQL Server Express Edition or SQL Server Developer Edition to do it. Purchasing SQL Server is not necessary.

Some data can be obtained from a backup without restoring it, but SQL Server is still required for this.

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\Path\To\Your\Backup.bak'
```

This command returns the database's metadata present in this backup, including the database name, server version, backup creation date, etc.

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY  FROM DISK = 'C:\Path\To\Your\Backup.bak'
```

This command returns information about the database files that made up the database at the time of backup.

[How to open a .bak file](https://sqlbak.com/blog/open-a-bak-file/)

[RESTORE HEADERONLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-headeronly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

[RESTORE FILELISTONLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-filelistonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)